# Чтение русских символов из файла - C++

Tags: c++

Не могу понять, в чем проблема. 
При чтении русских символов через wifstream из файла в wstring все равно появляются не русские символы, а бред какой-то(Ð³Ð´Ðµ).
[image]

Исходный код:

```
void    READER_THREAD(bool *READER_THREAD_CLOSE, std::wstring* FILE_PATH, unsigned int* lastError,
    std::vector<std::wstring>* MESSAGES_FROM_LOG, std::mutex* MESSAGES_FROM_LOG_ACCESS, std::mutex* LAST_ERROR_ACCESS)
{
    std::wifstream LOG_FILE;
    int lastSize = -1;
    LOG_FILE.open((*FILE_PATH));
    if (!LOG_FILE.is_open())
    {
        (*LAST_ERROR_ACCESS).lock();
        (*lastError) = ERR_WRONG_FILENAME;
        (*LAST_ERROR_ACCESS).unlock();
        return;
    }
    LOG_FILE.close();
    int x = 0; std::wstring buffer;
    while (!(*READER_THREAD_CLOSE))
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(THREAD_DELAY));
        if (SizeOFile((*FILE_PATH)) != lastSize)
        {
            x = 0;
            LOG_FILE.open((*FILE_PATH));
            (*MESSAGES_FROM_LOG_ACCESS).lock();
            int MESSAGE_FROM_LOG_SIZE = (*MESSAGES_FROM_LOG).size();
            (*MESSAGES_FROM_LOG_ACCESS).unlock();
            while (x < MESSAGE_FROM_LOG_SIZE - 1) if (getline(LOG_FILE, buffer)) x++;
            if (x >= MESSAGE_FROM_LOG_SIZE - 1)
            {
                (*MESSAGES_FROM_LOG_ACCESS).lock();
                while (getline(LOG_FILE, buffer)) (*MESSAGES_FROM_LOG).push_back(buffer);
                (*MESSAGES_FROM_LOG_ACCESS).unlock();
                lastSize = SizeOFile((*FILE_PATH));
            }
            LOG_FILE.close();
        }
        else std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(THREAD_DELAY));
    }
}
```

Comment: Надо полагать, файл в кодировке utf-8. А еще идентификаторы из всех заглавных букв обычно используются для макросов.

Comment: Если файл закодирован в utf-8, как это узнать? И что делать  с  этой информацией?

Comment: Например можно открыть файл в notepad++ и поглядеть в меню Encoding. А потом поглядеть вопрос про чтение utf8 файлов в wchar_t.